# Is there any free/paid geo data service available?

Tags: database, web-services, api, geo

I need to create two dropdowns for an app. One shows all countries the the world, the other is filled with all cities of a selected country in the first dropdown. Is there any web service or database that provides such information?

Comment: I found a 800+ MB data dump (.txt) for geonames.org that containing probably what I need. Anybody know any tool that can open such a HUGE .txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desmond

You can get a list of all the countries and all cities per country from a free database from MaxMind.com that is only 33Mb.

http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities

Andrew 
Part of the "OpenGeoCode.Org" Team

Answer (score 1):

Given that you found by yourself the answer to your question, I'll give the answer for what you ask in the comment:

Maybe [Boxer Text Editor](http://www.boxersoftware.com/pgfeat.htm) will do the trick:

> Large file capacity
>
> - edit files up to 2 GB in size
> - no theoretical limit on the number of open files
> - line lengths to 32K characters
> - total editing capacity is limited only by the operating system's virtual
>     memory capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Geonames has several [webservices](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) which basically give you programmatic access to that 800m db.

Answer (score 0):

I used the one at http://www.zuzemo.com
It has just about everything you need, countries, regions and cities